# Processing 4.0 | CANVAS

Tags: canvas, processing

This rendered image must have the following characteristics:

The canvas should be 700 pixels by 400 pixels
A dark/black background
A drawing of an x-wing that closely resembles the one in the image on the left-hand side of the panel. The pixels do not have to line up exactly, but it should be placed in a similar location and have a similar look. You should use at least two lines, two rectangles, one triangle, and eight ellipses. All of the shapes, colored lights, etc should appear in the same place.
A drawing of a tie-fighter that closely resembles the one in the image on the right-hand side of the panel. The pixels do not have to line up exactly, but it should be placed in a similar location and have a similar look. You should use three rectangles and two ellipses to draw it.
16 white stars, all of which should be visible (not behind any of the other drawings)
4 stars should be 5 pixels wide
4 stars should be 4 pixels wide
4 stars should be 3 pixels wide
4 stars should be 2 pixels wide
Ultimately, the image does not have to be pixel-for-pixel identical to the example. You may take some creative liberty, but it must be similar and fulfill all of the above requirements.

[image: picture of requires canvas]

Comment: "Processing 4.0 | CANVAS" - Is not a question.  The title of the question should briefly describe your problem and not include the list of tags.

Comment: Is this for a course at an educational institution?

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried so far? Where are you struggling?

Comment: You might wanna read about [how to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) answers and rethink how to post your question.